# web.config to .htacess

Tags: linux

i m migrate the one site from windows server to linux server,

it is working fine but index page only working, other pages not working, i m check this, for url redirect use the web.config this in not working in linux server, any one please convert this and give me

```
    <rule name="aboutuspage" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^About-Us/" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/about-us.php" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="newseventspage" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^News-Events/" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/gallery.php" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="qualitypage" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^Quality/" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/quality.php" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

please help this any one

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below htaccess code.

```
# Make sure that the rewrite module has been enabled
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Enable the RewriteEngine may be duplicate.
RewriteEngine on
# Base of website
RewriteBase /
# Check if it is a PHP **file**
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
#Writing it without .php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

If this is the solution, please accept my answer and eventually vote it up.